# PHP mysql - ...AND column='anything'...?

Tags: php, mysql, search, url, function

Is there any way to check if a column is "anything"? The reason is that i have a searchfunction that get's an ID from the URL, and then it passes it through the sql algorithm and shows the result. But if that URL "function" (?) isn't filled in, it just searches for:

```
...AND column=''...
```

and that doesn't return any results at all. I've tried using a "%", but that doesn't do anything.

Any ideas?

Here's the query:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM filer 
             WHERE real_name LIKE '%$searchString%' 
                   AND public='1' AND ikon='$tab' 
                   OR filinfo LIKE '%$searchString%' 
                   AND public='1' 
                   AND ikon='$tab' 
             ORDER BY rank DESC, kommentarer DESC");
```

The problem is "ikon=''"...

Comment: You have your query already wrong. Mixing AND and OR without a parenthesis will bring wrong results

Comment: Be careful about SQL injection attacks -- make sure you're escaping the variables in your query.  See also:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: I didn't know that, but it's working just like i want it now. And i didn't see any difference by changing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`and ikon like '%'` would check for the column containing "anything".  Note that `like` can also be used for comparing to literal strings with no wildcards, so, if you change that portion of SQL to use `like` then you could pre-set the variable to `'%'` and be all set.

However, as someone else mentioned below, beware of SQL injection attacks.  I always strongly suggest that people use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and prepared queries instead of relying on `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Answer (score 3):

Try using this:

```
AND ('$tab' = '' OR ikon = '$tab')
```

If the empty string is given then the condition will always succeed.

Alternatively, from PHP you could build two different queries depending on whether `$id` is empty or not.

Comment: Still no results. Before passing in the URL variable, i check if it's set, and if it's not, i set it to "". That's the same thing as: AND column='something' OR column='', right? Well, still not working anyways. :/

Comment: @Nike: No it's not the same. You need the parentheses.

Comment: Okey, it still gives me the same result though.

Comment: @Nike: You've typed `column=''` instead of `'$id' = ''`.

Comment: Actually, it's suppose to be " ikon='' " and not ID.

Comment: @Nike: My apologies, I was unable to guess your column names correctly. I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 3):

You can dynamically create your query, e.g.:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE foo='bar'";

if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $query .= " AND column='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "'";
}
```

**Update:** Updated code to be closer to the OP's question.

Comment: The presence of `AND` in the question implies that he always wants a `WHERE` clause, but that one of the clauses should be optional.

Comment: @Mark Byers: Yes, I know. It is only an example and I think it can be easily adapted to using `AND`. It should give the right idea. (Anyway, updated my example...)

Comment: That's a good idea! I'll keep that in mind for future use. This time however, i don't think that's a good idea to use.

Answer (score 0):

Run your query if search string is provided by wrapping it in `if-else` condition:

```
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];

if ($id)
{
  // run query
}
else
{
  // echo oops
}
```

Comment: Yeah i could do that, i've thought about it, but i don't want to clutter the code too much. Isn't there any way to just check if it's *?

Answer (score 0):

There is noway to check if a column is "anything"
The way to include all values into query result is **exclude** this field from the query.
But you can always build a query dynamically.
Just a small example:

```
$w=array();
if (!empty($_GET['rooms'])) $w[]="rooms='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['rooms'])."'";
if (!empty($_GET['space'])) $w[]="space='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['space'])."'";
if (!empty($_GET['max_price'])) $w[]="price < '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['max_price'])."'";


if (count($w)) $where="WHERE ".implode(' AND ',$w); else $where='';
$query="select * from table $where";
```

For your query it's very easy:

```
$ikon="";
if ($id) $ikon = "AND ikon='$tab'";
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM filer 
             WHERE (real_name LIKE '%$searchString%' 
                   OR filinfo LIKE '%$searchString%')
                   AND public='1' 
                   $ikon 
             ORDER BY rank DESC, kommentarer DESC");
```

I hope you have all your strings already escaped

Comment: Could you perhaps explain what the last IF statement actually does?

Comment: @Nike it is for the case if no criteria were passed.

Comment: Aaah, now suddenly everything makes more sense to me! :) That would however also clutter the code. If there is no easier way i think i'll go with a simple if statement. if(isset($_GET['foo'])){query..}else {another query...}

Comment: Oh, it seems even very simple code looks "clutter" to you. Next time I'll write slower.

Comment: Got your period or what? It's unnecessary  to write 6 lines of code to accomplish something that i just managed to do with a few words.

Comment: @Nike Lost your eyes? actually there is less code than yours. Way less. And I suspect the other your code is no better. Why not to learn from a guru how to code without "clutter" and say thanks?

Answer (score 0):

I take it that you are adding the values in from variables. The variable is coming and you need to do something with it - too late to hardcode a 'OR 1 = 1' section in there. You need to understand that LIKE isn't what it sounds like (partial matching only) - it does exact matches too. There is no need for 'field = anything' as:

- {field LIKE '%'} will give you everything
- {field LIKE 'specific_value'} will ONLY give you that value - it is not partial matching like it sounds like it would be.

Using 'specific_value%' or '%specific_value' will start doing partial matching. Therefore LIKE should do all you need for when you have a variable incoming that may be a '%' to get everything or a specific value that you want to match exactly. This is how search filtering behaviour would usually happen I expect.